# "generalization" of "algebraic limit theorem for functional limits"

Tags: real-analysis, limits

i'm interested to see if one can extend algebraic limit theorem (which require both function to bee convergent), in a "generalized" form that require only one function to be convergent.
in particular i'm looking to know what properties the not convergent function must have to work.

my work on that:

i think that an operation (for example addition) could be seen as a function with two variable, for example $f(x)+p(x)$ could be seen as $g(x,f(x))=f(x)+p(x)$ then in general $g(x,y)=y+p(x)$.
in this case the propiety that would be required to $p(x)$ to hold would be  that:

if $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}(f(x))=c$ then $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}(g(x,f(x)))=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}g(x,c)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it can't have such a generalization.

Suppose that a function $f$ is convergent and $g$ is not. Then certainly $f+g$ is not convergent. Indeed, if $(f+g)$ was convergent, then, using that $g =(f+g) - f$, the algebraic limit theorem would imply that $g$ is convergent (contradiction).

The only way you can get $f+g$ convergent in your context (that is, when not both functions are convergent) is when both functions $f$, $g$ are non-convergent.